# Fastest type for std::map key?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, types, key

I would like to use the partitions of a graph as the key to a std::map

I could represent this as a std vector of nodes.  Or I could convert it into a more compact 'custom' binary format (bitset?), or a string representation.

For simplicitiy's sake, we can say there is no inherent order to partitions of a graph.

Which will be fastest in terms of insertions and lookups (note the size of this map will be in the order of a billion nodes)

Comment: Probably you want an `unordered_map` instead of `map`.

Comment: Of course, `unordered_map` is only available if you are using a C++0x compiler.

Comment: @Billy: It is available in TR1 and Boost also.

Comment: @KennyTM: For some reason I thought you had written a `std::` in front of that. My bad :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to have that many entries and performance is critical, I would suggest to definitely use `unordered_map`.

If you are using C++1x it's in the standard library; otherwise you can get it from [boost](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html).

If performance is *really* critical you can go even further and use [boost::intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/intrusive.html). It contains "intrusive" versions of the standard library containers: they copy the pointers of the values you insert instead of the values themselves. If the values are large you'll get a big performance benefit.

Answer (score 4):

Keep your key type, but use boost's `unordered_map` and write your own `hash()` function for your graph partition.

For example, if order doesn't matter, you can hash each node in a way that is invariant to order. If you post how you are encoding it now, we can help more with this.

Comment: Currently a partition is  stored as array of 64 bit integers where each long comprises a group and each bit in that long denotes whether a node is a member of that group.  E.g. 0101, 1010 Would mean nodes 0 and  2 belong to group 0 and nodes 1 and 3 belong to group 1 of the partition

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reliably answer this question is the only way to answer ANY optimization question: Try it and see.

That said, I doubt there'd be much difference between the two, so long as there is an efficient comparison operator you can use.